# Converting form with repeat elements to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Apologies if this has been covered elsewhere, I couldn't find anything

I have an html form like this:

```
<form>
  <div>
  First Name <input name="FirstName" type="text">
  Age <input name="Age" type="number">
  </div>

  <div>
  First Name  <input name="FirstName" type="text">
  Age <input name="Age" type="number">
  </div>

  <div>
  First Name <input name="FirstName" type="text">
  Age <input name="Age" type="number">
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

And I have jquery code like this:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Which returns results like this:

```
{"FirstName":["tom","dick","harry"],"Age":[22,35,40]}
```

Whereas I would like it to return results like this:

```
[{"FirstName": "Tom","Age": 22},{"FirstName": "Dick","Age": 35},{"FirstName": "Harry","Age": 42}]
```

Very grateful if anyone can help me out as i'm new to this and can't tell how to do it

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to process div one by one, replacing `$('form').serializeObject()` with:

```
$('form > div')
    .map(function(){
        return $(this).find(':input').serializeObject();
    })
    .get()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a class to the `div`'s can do something like:

HTML:

```
<div class="group">
  First Name <input name="FirstName" type="text" value="Foo">
  Age <input name="Age" type="number" value="27">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$.fn.serializeGroups=function(){
    var results=[];
    $(this).find('.group').each(function(){
        var o={};
        $(this).find('input').each(function(){
            o[this.name]=this.value;
        });
        results.push(o);        
    });
    return results;    
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d6751res/1/)**</kbd>

Assumes all inputs have `name`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary variable and a counter

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = [];
    var a = this.serializeArray();

    var count=0;
    var r = {};
    $.each(a, function() {
        r[this.name]= this.value || '';
        if( (count%2) == 1){
            o.push(r);
            r = {};
        }       
    });
    return o;
};
```